# Is this the correct way to get the state space representation of this system?

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory

[image]

In this exercise the state space representation of the imaged system is asked for.
$$G_1(s) = \frac{s-1}{s+2} = 1 - \frac{3}{s+2} G_2(s)=\frac{1}{s-1}$$
I can see that $G_1(s)$ is "able to leap" (hope it is the correct translation of sprungfähig), because nominator and denominator have the same order.

So for the system matrix I get $$A = \begin{pmatrix} -2 & 3  \\1 & 0  \end{pmatrix}$$
That should be correct.
But I am not sure with B and C.
Can I get both by looking at the image? Because that is what I did and it looks plausible.
$$B = \begin{pmatrix} -3  \\ 1  \end{pmatrix}$$
$$C = \begin{pmatrix} 0  \\1   \end{pmatrix}$$

And does the output y look like this, because of the leapable ability?
$$ y= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1   \end{pmatrix} x + d = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1   \end{pmatrix} x + 1$$

Differential equations:
$$\frac{dx_1}{dt} = -2x_1+3x_2-3r$$
$$\frac{dx_2}{dt} = x_1+r$$

Matrix B
Matrix B is the control matrix, and determines how the system input affects the state change. If the state change is not dependent on the system input, then B will be the zero matrix.

Matrix C
Matrix C is the output matrix, and determines the relationship between the system state and the system output.

Comment: I don't know how you computed the feedback loop but you can check the validity of your representation by the resulting transfer function. Besides I think you would end up with a first order system since there is a pole-zero cancellation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
G_1G_2 = \frac{1}{s+2}
$$
Then, the transfer function from $r$ to $y$ is given by 
$$
G_{yr} = \frac{G_1 G_2}{1+G_1G_2} = \frac{1}{s+3}
$$
A state space representation for this is 
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{c|c}
A &B\\ \hline C& D 
\end{array}\right]= 
\left[ \begin{array}{c|c}
-3 &1\\ \hline 1& 0 
\end{array}\right]
$$

Comment: Yes, that is how I did it first. But in my exercise class we did this example. There I was told to make a polynomial division with $G_1$ because of this leapability.

Comment: Added some the differential equations and $G_1$.

Comment: @madmax What is leapability? This is the first time that I hear about it.

Comment: @madmax You will get a state space representation.Use $C(sI-A)^{-1}B$ to obtain the transfer function. You would get, $    \frac{s - 1}{s^2 + 2 s - 3}$ which can be simplified to $1/(s+3)$.

Comment: I wrote that in my question. ;-) I think I translated it wrong. The system has the ability to jump. Does this help?

Comment: But how did you get your matrix out of your transfer function? Is your matrix equal to my A matrix?

Comment: @madmax I used the simple technique that I wrote in one of your earlier questions.

Comment: I assume you were referring to this answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70037/how-to-obtain-a-possible-state-space-representation-of-this-2nd-order-transfer-fu). But I don't know how you got the A matrix values out of y(t) and u(t).

Comment: It is not valid do a pole zero cancellation before converting to state space because then you only get the $u$ to $y$ dynamics, not the whole $x$ dynamics.